# How to open custom files?

Tags: objective-c, file

I have successfully made a custom file type based on a text file. I have put an open command in my application, which works perfectly. My problem is that when I double click on one of my files, it opens my application, but it tells me that I app cannot open those files.

My code is as follows.

Files.h

```
@interface Files : NSObject {
    IBOutlet id name;
}

- (IBAction) open: (id) sender;
```

Files.m

```
- (IBAction) open: (id) sender; {
    NSOpenPanel *theOpenPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hsc", @"HSC", nil];
    [theOpenPanel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
    if ([theOpenPanel runModal] == NSOKButton) {
        NSString *theFileName = [theOpenPanel filename];
        NSString *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:theFileName];
        [name setStringValue:data];

    }
}
```

When I tell my program to open the file, it puts all of the data in as needed. When I double click on my file, nothing happens.

Important Note: I just found out that ".hsc" is a file used in Windows 7. I am going to change my file extension after I solve this problem.

Comment: Could your file extension *be* the problem?

Comment: No. The file is fine. I am just changing the file extension so Windows users don't get confused if they see it, or if they use the Windows version of the app (if I ever make one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename
```

in your AppDelegate class to handle loading the file. Make sure to return YES from this method to indicate the file was successfully opened.

Comment: It stills says it cannot open them. How can I implement your code to make it work?

Comment: @Justin - Make sure this method is getting called when you double-click a file of your format, by putting in an NSLog. Then use the same loading code you use when opening through the open dialog to process the opening of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now; I don't see how I could have missed it.